# jQuery hasClass() with dynamic value

Tags: jquery

I have the below code.

What I am tryng to do is when I click on an item in **"section1"** it then adds/removes a class (hides/shows) in the matching item in **section 2**.

e.g. If I click on **section1 > id = "group1"**, then in **section2 > class = "group1"** it adds a class, and removes a class from all the others.

The problem is that the "section1 > id" is created dynamically as part of a PHP script.

I can get the ID into a variable, but it seems that I can't use that variable in the `hasClass()` function.

How would I go about this?

```
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function()
      {
        $('body').on('click','.click_button',function()
        {
            groupId = $(this).attr('id');

            $('.group_inner').removeClass('displayItem').addClass('hiddenItem');
            $('.group_inner').hasClass(groupId).removeClass('hiddenItem').addClass('displayItem');
        })
      })
  </script>

  <div id="section1">
    <div id="group_1" class="click_button">group_1</div>
    <div id="group_2" class="click_button">group_2</div>
    <div id="group_3" class="click_button">group_3</div>
  </div>

  <div id ="section2">
    <div id="section_1" class="group_inner group_1 displayItem">group_1</div>
    <div id="section_2" class="group_inner group_2 hiddenItem">group_2</div>
    <div id="section_3" class="group_inner group_3 hiddenItem">group_3</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `hasClass` returns a boolean.  You want to `filter()`

Comment: Small side note; `$(this).attr('id');` should be just `this.id`.  There's no need to use jQuery to get an already exposed property on the Element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter by class.

```
$('.group_inner').filter('.'+ groupId).removeClass('hiddenItem').addClass('displayItem');
```

Or without a filter

```
$('.group_inner.'+ groupId).removeClass('hiddenItem').addClass('displayItem');
```